# Error opening a new browser window using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, new-window

```
<script>
        function myFunction() {
        var myWindow = window.open("http://www.w3schools.com" "width=200, height=100);
        }
    </script>

<a href="terms.html" onclick="myFunction()"> Terms and Conditions</a> in this term and conditions I have an onclick that calls `myFunction()` and i justenter code here have w3school as an example
```

For the `onclick` does it have to go to a published website or can it be a html file i have saved on my hardrive called `terms.html`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your direct question, you should be able to run this from a file on your local computer.

However, you have a syntax error in your javascript.  You are missing a comma and quote mark in your parameter list on the call to `window.open()`

Instead of:

`var myWindow = window.open("http://www.w3schools.com" "width=200, height=100);`

try this:

`var myWindow = window.open("http://www.w3schools.com", "width=200, height=100");`